# What direction is the wave traveling in?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, geophysics

[image]

I don't understand how one can derive the direction of travel of the wave just using equations for displacement. I believe it might be related to the wave equation which helps with other parameters such as amplitude, wavelength, etc but I'm not sure. It also want to know if you can find what kind of wave it is (P,SH, or SV) using just the equations for displacement, and if so is it by using another type of equation?

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Factor x and Y as a dot product. Here it's in the form K dot R
Where K is your wave vector